# Is there a real-time Linux distro that achieves nanosecond-level latency?

Tags: linux, operating-system, signal-processing, real-time

Is it possible to run general purpose Linux OS on DSPs and get guaranteed latency?

I may be wrong, but in my impression current general purpose CPUs (e.g., x86) are not yet powerful enough to achieve ns latency when processing digital signals. Is it a hardware performance mismatch, or just our general purpose software (e.g., OS) can only achieve millisecond latency at best?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have hard real-time requirements, then an OS designed for that environment is the right OS.

Comment: What do you even mean 'latency when processing digital signals'??  Intervals between interrupt signal and interrupt-acknowledge ?

Comment: Linux patched with the PREEMPT_RT patchset can achieve deterministic latencies of under 100 microseconds, but is nowhere near being capable of nanosecond-level latencies.

Answer (score 2):

There are non-homogeneous multiprocessor chips that allow running Linux (or uCLinux) on one core (ARM A5 for instance), and an RTOS on another core (ARM M0 or M4 for instance).

If you want guaranteed nanosecond-level latency, you need a processor that can run both your interrupt and DSP code using a dedicated (non-task-switched) register set (or sets) and un-cached local memory for both data and the executable code.  Otherwise, any thread/task dispatch/switching state-save-restore flush/fill might vary your fixed-cycle latency.  Under any general multi-tasking OS, that currently seems to require at least one additional dedicated processor or core (or barrel thread with dedicated resources and time slot).